# Does the "running" tag need to be more granular?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is one question about [first aid kits for long distance running](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/first-aid-kit-for-long-distance-running). The user added a request in the question for a [long-distance-running](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/long-distance-running) tag.

> P.s. please, create label long-distance-running. Running is a bit
>   vague here, this is quite different thing -- more about endurance
>   running and sometimes related to other activity such as trekking. But
>   the common element to carry first-aid-kit is long-distance and unknown
>   places so you need to be better prepared than locally.

Should the [running](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/running) tag be broken up? What are the arguments for or against it?

**EDIT:** Dave's answer makes sense here. Retag things as necessary as they come up. No need to plan out *everything* right now.

Comment: Is there actually a reason why tags aren't combined separately? Would it be that long-distance then in itself would no longer have a meaning?

Comment: @hhh Please move your arguments to your answer.

Comment: @MattChan: sorry I am confused. @IvoFlipse: can you clarify? @everyone: someone with better ideas for the current naming? Is `long-distance` enough? (I think it is vague, long-distance-running is better as more specific.) `Long-distance-runing != marathon`. I think we should see how things evolve (I have organized already some questions so you see how different things are under them.). *P.s. we can change things later if we see the labels are misused.*

Comment: ...related running proposal [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6530/running/6597#6597). If this site begins, then it will become more granual for sure.

Comment: @hhh My point was that the arguments you were making in the comments should have been added to your answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running is the most-used tag right now, and it sure is broad. I don't see any good reason not to subdivide it.

I'm in favor of adding sprinting and long-distance running tags. We could keep the general case.

Comment: +1 yes not bad idea at all. Good ideas! Sprinting is totally different thing to long-distance: shoes tend to be different, training, muscle types, nutrition recs,.... For common issues, it is good to have more broad `"running"`. I find this division a bit similar to touring and commuter in Bicycle.SE. The fact that we have legs and most of us can run does not mean that everyone mean the same thing with their `"running"`, it makes communication/searching much easier if we can separate the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is good idea here to create consintency between different SE sites, particularly here between Bicycle.SE and Fitness.SE.

```
running ---> long-distance (running)
-----------> fast (sprinting)
-----------> casual (jogging)
-----------> training (?)
-----------> other?

riding ----> long-distance (touring)
-----------> fast (?)
-----------> casual (commuting)
-----------> training(?)
-----------> other?
```

I would like to subdivide `running` because it is bloated now. Running is a bit like `riding`: `running/sprinting/long-distance-running/marathon/XYZ ~ riding/training/touring/commuting/XYZ`. Now I am not sure whether it is even possible to create some consistency here, perhaps, community blog could cover similarities between the sites to help people find things?

Comment: I don't see particular utility in generalizing across SE sites. Doing so would either automate the process, thereby creating inaccuracies, or would require me to argue with Biking people to change something in Fitness. No me gusta.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann: *Jein!* It is mostly a redirection thing, there is no need to talk with bicycle guys or future sport site guys (although architect may help). It is possible to create redirections from specific sites to other sites with redirecting stuff -- and I do not see much division here between stuff such as `endurance` over many sites (even some users are the same over such issues...). Now just important to `connect the dots` over such issues not to reinvent the dxmn wheel again-and-again. Until proper redirections, it is essential to keep different things separate with specific labeling.

Comment: If you're proposing simply that we should poach ideas from other SE sites, then I agree wholeheartedly and would humbly point out forthwith that we--as individuals, a group and as a nation--are already doing so with utmost haste. If you are proposing something technical, something requiring administrative intervention, or some regulated process, then I call that idea a roustabout, unsuitable for this fine establishment.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann: you are making this overly complicated. There is no pro skills required except tolerance for new ideas, no revolution or any extreme -- just some good manner skills required to tolerate other ideas. This question in Meta is in itself large distraction, just see how things evolve. I recommend to keep intrinsic things separate, we can change labeling later from `long-distance` to other when needed. Currently, I see no point to intervene with running community to jam everything under `running`. No spaghetti, please, with political rhetoric that builds on nothing. Have fuN!